# Authentication on NodeJS OpenID Identity Provider Server

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, openid, openid-provider

I'm pretty new with all this so this might be a stupid question, just trying to get a better understanding. I need to make an identity provider server, but I'm not sure how to go about some steps after that. If I create an identity provider server using node-oidc-provider, do I also need oidc-client to authenticate through myself?

I can't figure out how to let users login to my service and be available as an identity provider through node-oidc-provider. I have a login/registration system setup but I'm not sure how to get it going with this. Certain routes are protected that require login for my service, so I was wondering if it was possible for me to do this all through oidc-provider or if I also need to use oidc-client for the same server.

node-oidc-provider: https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider

Main thing I'm confused on it, logging in and using my service through the provider library, and protecting routes through the same way. For example, `/profile` or `/admin` route should require being logged in/authenticated and verified to access.

Comment: I totally feel your pain. Hopefully this example will help you.
https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider-example A step by step guide to get a solution working on heroku.